# How can I get curated data to be expressed consistently in SI units?

Tags: curated-data, units, astronomy

`AstronomicalData` objects are consistently in SI units:

```
AstronomicalData["Mars", "Radius"]
(* Quantity[3.386*10^6, "Meters"] *)

AstronomicalData["Mars", "Density"]
(* Quantity[3934.0, ("Kilograms")/("Meters")^3] *)
```

However, `PlanetData` objects are not consistent anymore (miles are not cgs!):

```
PlanetData["Mars", "Radius"]
(* Quantity[2104., "Miles"] *)

PlanetData["Mars", "Density"]
(* Quantity[3.9340, ("Grams")/("Centimeters")^3] *)
```

Is there any way to force *Mathematica* into using consistent units and, even better, into SI units? I do not want to use `UnitConvert` as this makes the code really unreadable, what I want is curated data delivered in SI units.

Comment: At least, `PlanetData["Mars", "Radius"]` will now return a result in kilometers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the beginning of your notebook set the Metric system as default.

```
$UnitSystem = "Metric"
```

This works for me. If not try below suggestion
Remember you are reading the data from wolfram alpha!
it's a regional thing so if the upper solution didn't work, you can try something like (I don't remember exactly though)

```
SetOptions[WolframAlpha, PodStates -> {"Show metric"}]
```

Comment: Thank you, that at least gives answers in km instead of miles. However, the inconsistency is still there (cgs for `PlanetData` and SI for `AstronomicalData`).